# Example R source code for multiple linear regression with looping through geographies & products?

Tags: r, export-to-excel, linear-regression

pardon the newbie question, as I just started learning R a couple weeks ago (but intend to use it actively from now on). However, I could use some help if you already have a working example.

In order to determine own price elasticity coefficients for our each of our products (~100) in each of our states, I want to be able to write a multiple regression that regresses Units on a variety of independent variables. That's straightforward. However, I would like R to be able to cycle through EACH product within a particular state, THEN move onto the next state in the data file, and start the regression on the first product, repeating the cycle.

I have attached an example of what I'm trying to accomplish. I would also like R at the end to export the regression coefficients (and summaries, p-value, t-stat) into a separate worksheet.

Does anyone have an example similar to this? I'm comfortable enough to read the source code and make modifications to fit my needs, but certainly not yet comfortable at this point to write one from scratch. And, alas, I am tired of copying/pasting into Minitab/Excel (which is what i've been using up to this point) to run regressions 1,000 times.

Appreciate any help you could offer!

Comment: I think you should start by learning how to run a regression and then learn how to use the apply functions to apply the regression function to your data set. It would also help to read and learn `plyr`.

Comment: See this previous answer on [linear models with `ddply`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523427/ddply-with-lm-function).  Not exactly what you're looking for, but should get you started.

Comment: You say you've attached an example but I can't see it?? You should really include representative example of your data as well.