# multiple linear regression with apply or loop? in R

Tags: r

I would like to do multiple linear regression between more variables (a and b and c) for each day, but in reality I will have 5 or 6 data points for each day. Than I want to create new columns of the regression coefficients (intercept and slopes).

The data are something like this

```
Date        a      b        c
1.1.2004    4,8  12,9   5633,0
2.1.2004    1,8  11,5   6166,0
3.1.2004    3,9  15,2   5830,0
4.1.2004    6,8  14,3   2744,0
5.1.2004    5,9  14,2   3422,0
```

I tried `apply`

```
apply(data,1, function(x,y) lm(a~c, data=data))
```

but I am getting the same coefficients for each day and I still do not know how should I create the two columns with ceofficients.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523427/ddply-with-lm-function

Comment: or use `nlme::lmList` or `lme4::lmList`

Comment: now that I look more carefully, this doesn't really make sense -- why are you running a linear model with a single data point?  Why not just calculate the slope yourself?

Comment: Many different linear regression models could perfectly fit a single row of your dataset. For instance, a model with intercept of that row's `a` value and slope `0` or a model with intercept `0` and slope that row's `a/c` value. Could you describe what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your real data set contains more than only one data point per day, otherwise (as @BenBolker already said in comments) there is no sense to run a linear regression on it. Anyway, you could do something like that in `data.table` package. Try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(Interecept = lm(a ~ c)$coefficients[1],
                  coeff = lm(a ~ c)$coefficients[2]), by = Date]
```

Comment: Thank you, that is something what I needed. My data are from more years and from more weather stations. I want to do a regression between two variables per different time periods (months, or weeks). For the different days a have data from more meteo stations.

Comment: How can I extract another coeficients, for example if I ad variables to the formula lm(a~c+b+d),

Comment: just add another parameter inside the `list`, for example `, coeff2 = lm(a ~ c + b + d)$coefficients[3], coeff3 = lm(a ~ c + b + d)$coefficients[4]` and ofcorse update the models in the first two variables (`Intercept` and `coeff`)

Comment: have you any suggestions why my coeff2 is NA? `setDT(SLSP)[,list(Interecept=lm(SL_T_mean~SL_T_max+SL_Sol_rad)$coefficients[1],
            coeff=lm(SL_T_mean~SL_T_max+SL_Sol_rad)$coefficients[2],
            coeff2=lm(SL_T_mean~SL_T_max+SL_Sol_rad)$coefficients[3]),
            by = Date]`

Comment: could be many reasons, see here for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337761/linear-regression-na-estimate-just-for-last-coefficient